# Convert JSON to BPMN2 XML format in joint.js

Tags: xml, json, jointjs

Can I convert the graph object of joint.js into bpmn2 xml format?

If yes, how it can be done then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either loop over all the elements and links of the graph and generate the BPMN2 xml format (use the following methods for walking through the graph: `graph.getElements()`, `graph.getLinks()`, `graph.getConnectedLinks()`) or you can generate JSON out of the graph (`graph.toJSON()`) and write a converter of that JSON to the BPMN2 xml.

Comment: bpmn2 is a standard format. jsoint.js works with it format according description. why should I  implement all these steps manually? It seems a little bit crazy to me.

Comment: Currently, there is no support (and mention for that matter) in JointJS library for BPMN 2 XML format. Rappid - the JointJS extension contains BPMN shapes (http://jointjs.com/rappid/docs/shapes/bpmn) and can be used to create a BPMN application but it does not contain a converter from diagram to BPMN 2 XML format.